# Confusing setter and getter? Why does using the setter throw 'str' object is not callable?

Tags: python, class, properties, setter

I heard that using getter and setter functions such as `set_value()` and `get_value()` isn't Pythonic, and it is always better to use a `property` object with a setter and getter.

I ran the code below, and I get an error `'str' object is not callable'`. When I search for this error, I find many examples of code where the class have an attribute and a method with the same name  (like if I write  `self.name` instead of  `self.__name` in the `__init__` method).

But I have used two underscores before the attribute - so it shouldn't have happened here. It looks like when I try to call `name.setter` I actually call a property, and receive back the string stored in `self.__name` - and it is to this string I then tried to call something else.

But why? In all examples of setter, they have the same name as property and it doesn't lead to problem. Why does it throw an error here, and how do I fix it?

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name_in):
        self.__name = name_in

dog = Dog("Barbos")
print(dog.name)                 # this works
dog.name("Juchka")              # and this throws an error: 
                                # TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Setter is used like: `dog.name = "Juchka"`

Comment: A setter is there to hook into **assignment**. You'd use `dog.name = "Juchka"`.

Comment: You use a setter as `dog.name = 'newname'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still thinking in terms of methods here. A setter is *not directly called*. Instead, a setter is called when you *assign to the name*.

Use assignment:

```
dog.name = "Juchka"
```

Python translates this into a call to the setter method.

Just accessing `dog.name` calls the getter, and the getter method returned a string.  Calling is a separate expression from looking up the object to apply the call *to*; `dog.name("Juchka")` first executes `dog.name`, and applies the `("Juchka")` call expression to the result of that attribute lookup. The attribute lookup returned `"Barbos"`, and `"Barbos"("Juchka")` indeed does not work.

Demo:

```
>>> dog = Dog("Barbos")
>>> dog.name
'Barbos'
>>> 'Barbos'("Juchka")  # what really happens when you try to call dog.name(...)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> dog.name = "Juchka"
>>> dog.name
'Juchka'
```